# Pandas take average over regular intervals of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe like such:

```
    Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5 Col_6
0     1     2     3     4     5     6
1     7     8     9     10    11    12
```

I'd like to take the average over subsets of columns, defined by some given interval. Say the interval is two, then I want to take the average of Col_1 and Col_2, Col_3 and Col 4 as well as Col_5 and Col6. Or given an interval of 3, I'd like the output to be

```
    First_Avg  Second_Avg
0      2          5
1      8          11
```

It is to be assumed that I cannot go off the naming of my columns.
Code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Col_'+str(n) for n in range(1,7)], data =np.arange(12).reshape(2,6))
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you actually tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @AMC this question is already answered and the question is quite clearly stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is create `np.arange` by length of columns and then use integer division for groups, pass it to `groupby` with `axis=1` and aggregate `mean`:

```
N = 2
df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1).mean().add_prefix('Avg_')
print (df1)
   Avg_0  Avg_1  Avg_2
0    1.5    3.5    5.5
1    7.5    9.5   11.5

N = 3
df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1).mean().add_prefix('Avg_')
print (df1)
   Avg_0  Avg_1
0      2      5
1      8     11
```

**Details**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 2)
[0 0 1 1 2 2]

print (np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

EDIT: If only few columns in output is possible create dictionary by new columns names and then use `rename`:

```
d = {0:'bar', 1:'baz', 2:'foo'}
N = 2
df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1).mean().rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
   bar  baz   foo
0  1.5  3.5   5.5
1  7.5  9.5  11.5
```

For more general solution with generated columns names by uppercase alphabets use:

```
import string
d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase))

N = 2
df1 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N, axis=1).mean().rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
     A    B     C
0  1.5  3.5   5.5
1  7.5  9.5  11.5
```

Comment: you're the ninja of helpful pandas advice :D thank you, once again.

Comment: do you happen to know how I would give the new columns pre-specified names?

Comment: @emilaz - Do you need `First`, Second?

Answer (score 0):

I will do `split` from `numpy`

```
pd.concat([x.mean(1)for x in np.split(df, [3], axis=1)],1)
     0     1
0  2.0   5.0
1  8.0  11.0
```